# python script hangs when calling cursor.fetchall() with large data set

Tags: python, mysql-connector

I have a query that returns over 125K rows.

The goal is to write a script the iterates through the rows, and for each, populate a second table with data processed from the result of the query.

To develop the script, I created a duplicate database with a small subset of the data (4126 rows)

On the small database, the following code works:

```
import os
import sys
import random

import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='dbuser', password='thePassword',
                          host='127.0.0.1',
                          database='db')
cnx_out = mysql.connector.connect(user='dbuser', password='thePassword',
                          host='127.0.0.1',
                          database='db')

ins_curs = cnx_out.cursor()

curs = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)
#curs = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True,buffered=True) #fail

with open('sql\\getRawData.sql') as fh:
    sql = fh.read()

curs.execute(sql, params=None, multi=False)
result = curs.fetchall()  #<=== script stops at this point
print len(result) #<=== this line never executes

print curs.column_names

curs.close()
cnx.close()
cnx_out.close()
sys.exit()
```

The line `curs.execute(sql, params=None, multi=False)` succeeds on both the large and small databases.
If I use `curs.fetchone()` in a loop, I can read all records.

If I alter the line:

```
curs = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

to read:

```
curs = cnx.cursor(dictionary=True,buffered=True)
```

The script hangs at `curs.execute(sql, params=None, multi=False)`.

I can find no documentation on any limits to fetchall(), nor can I find any way to increase the buffer size, and no way to tell how large a buffer I even need.

There are no exceptions raised.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Sounds like you already know of a way to get the result you want. Why don't you just do that? Clearly, trying to load a large amount of data all at once is hard. Why do you insist on doing that when you already have a solution that a) works b) does not load such a large amount of data at once?

Comment: Sorry, I should have anticipated the question.
Unless I fetch all rows, I cannot use the connection for anything else until I've done so -- even if I fetch them one at a time.  Apart from that, I need to be able to tell when fetchall() will crash a script.  Either that or just never use it at all.

Comment: You should probably rename your question to "When does fetchall() crash a script?"

Comment: How much data does 125K rows represent? How's your RAM usage while the script is hanging?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. In my case, my RAM usage is well under my computer's limit. This seems to be a pretty significant problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue, first on a query that returned ~70k rows and then on one that only returned around 2k rows (and for me RAM was also not the limiting factor). I switched from using mysql.connector (i.e. the mysql-connector-python package) to MySQLdb (i.e. the mysql-python package) and then was able to fetchall() on large queries with no problem. Both packages seem to follow the python DB API, so for me MySQLdb was a drop-in replacement for mysql.connector, with no code changes necessary beyond the line that sets up the connection. YMMV if you're leveraging something specific about mysql.connector.

Pragmatically speaking, if you don't have a specific reason to be using mysql.connector the solution to this is just to switch to a package that works better!